# 'then' expected near 'OR'

Tags: lua

Can't figure out whats the problem here! Shouldnt this work?

```
if getPlayerJob(playerid) == 2 OR getPlayerJob(playerid) == 8 then 
say("Hello my friend. How may I help you?")
elseif getPlayerJob(playerid) == 6 OR getPlayerJob(playerid) == 12 then
say("I dont talk to your kind.")
else
say("Hello.")
end
```

Comment: Lua is case-sensitive. Try `or` instead.

Comment: darn i forgot about that! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `OR` instructions should be lowercase (i.e. `or`).